# xCode 8 all iPhones same size class so what to do?

Tags: constraints, traits, xcode8

Simpe layout with suggested constraints. one is iPhone 7+ other iPhone 4s. Both devices are deemed as width Compact height Regular so applying different traits with xcode 8s `vary for Traits` option would be pointless. How to acheive the quite obvious aim of having the contraints and view resize according to the screen on which they are displayed?

[image: iPhone 7+ screen size]

[image: iPhone 4s screen size]

My aim is to have the constraints and 2 coloured views resize in proportion to the different screen sizes. But they do not.

How is this achieved in xcode 8?

Comment: Have you found anything related to it ?

Comment: No. Just ended up giving up